# how to convert multiple cell array (having different matrix size say[2x4 double][1x4 double] etc) to a matrix array using matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

How to convert multiple cell array (having different matrix size say [2x4 double] [1x4 double] [3x4 int32]....etc) to matrix array using Matlab?

here i want to have another array out of this array having elements only of dimension [7964x1 double] ignoring all other cells...

[image: here i want to have another array out of this array having elements only of dimension [7964x1 double] ignoring all other cells...]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to create 1D column array out fo your data by doing something like `:` operation on your cell array ?

Comment: What kind of operation do you want to perform on each matrix?

Comment: i want to have a 1D column array having all elements of equal size and type.

Comment: tried using cell2mat in a loop?

Comment: You arrays inside the cell have different lengths (302, 1154, 7964 etc.). Are you going to pad some value to the remaining positions in the matrix?

Comment: I want to keep values having length 7964 only discarding the remaining....